# How can I pass an object as an argument to one of its member functions?

Tags: c++

I created a class bigInt in c++. While overloading some of its operators, I need to pass the object itself as an argument to one of its member functions. I know that I can do this with `*this`. I can also do it by creating another object of the same class with the same member variables and pass it as an argument. But is there any way I can skip `*this` and also not create another object?

Here is the code I have made using `*this`:

```
using namespace std;
class bigInt {
private:
    string value;

public:
    template<class T>
    bigInt(T x) {
        //.... .... ....constructor
    }

    bigInt operator+ (bigInt num) {
        //... ... ... my code here
    }

    template<class T>
    bigInt operator+ (T x) {
        return *this + bigInt(x);
    }
};
```

And here is the code where I created another object of the class bigInt:

```
using namespace std;
class bigInt {
private:
    string value;

public:
    template<class T>
    bigInt(T x) {
        //.... .... ....constructor
    }

    bigInt operator+ (bigInt num) {
        //... ... ... my code here
    }

    template<class T>
    bigInt operator+ (T x) {
        return bigInt(value) + bigInt(x);
    }
};
```

Please tell me how I can do the same thing without using `*this` or creating another object?

N.B. I heard that using the `this` pointer is generally considered a bad programming practice. Is it true or not? If it is true, is there any case where it is not considered a bad practice?

**Update:** It's perfectly okay to use `*this` in this context. The article that inspired me to ask this question was talking about something else completely. But as a newbie programmer, I didn't understand the context there.

Comment: Do you have a reference/link for "using the this pointer is generally considered a bad programming practice"?  I'm pretty sure it's exactly the correct practice when you need to refer to the current object

Comment: Why not just use a namespace-scoped `operator+`, rather than a member function?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using  `*this` where appropriate.  You _should_ probably pass your parameters as const  references, though.

Comment: **−1** The code is not the real code, but rather code that the OP thinks is **irrelevant**.

Answer (score 0):

The templated operator+ is superfluous; just remove it.

---

In other news:

- Consider also changing `bigInt operator+ (bigInt num)` to `bigInt operator+ (bigInt const& num)` to avoid needless inefficiency.
- Also, consider making it a `friend` function so that order of arguments doesn't matter.

Comment: In my original code I did not use templated operator+. I used it here just to express the problem I have. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the friend function? How will it help me to pass the object as a parameter?

Comment: A friend function has access to the non-`public` parts of the class, but is a non-member function. As such `operator+` has two explicit arguments.

Comment: This code is not irrelevent. It resembles my code perfectly. I just did not want to make my question a really huge one by giving  my complete code  which is more than 500 lines long. That's why I used template here to show you the problem that I have. Giving my whole code here would be a waste of time, both yours and mine.